# Zend Framework: How to get default param?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

How do I get the 'default' param if not specified?

Consider the following:

```
http://localhost/controller/action/id/123
```

In my controller, I can get the value of 'id' using

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$id = $request->getParam('id');
```

If the URL is

```
http://localhost/controller/action/456
```

how do I get the value of 456?
What is the 'param' name?

Comment: And what if when i want to use more parameters like http://localhost/controller/action/456?otherparameter=foo&thirdparam=bar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ZF URL have to follow pattern:

```
/controller/action/param1Name/param1Val/param2Name/param2Val ...
```

You should use [router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).  For example in `bootstrap.php`:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
//^^^this line should be already there

$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'yourController/yourAction/:id',
    array(
        'id'       => 1, //default value
        'controller' => 'yourController',
        'action'     => 'yourAction'
    ),
    array('id' => '\d+')
);
$router->addRoute('yourController', $route);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this router? In the doc says in Controller. Is it controllers/myController.php? or in bootstrap.php file? 
TQ!

Comment: it's referring to frontend controller

Comment: Thank you. Just to share that I need to put all this before dispatching the front controller.

<above code goes here>
 
// Dispatch the request using the front controller. 
$frontController->dispatch ();

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share.

The above router setting must be used with the $frontController.

And be sure put it before the controller dispatches.

```
<..above router code goes here...>

// Dispatch the request using the front controller. 
$frontController->dispatch ();
```

Hope don't waste time like myself. ;-)

Comment: Of course. That's why I've suggested putting that in bootstrap.php, which is called before dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this route to router:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'my_controller/my_action/(\d+)',
    array(
        'controller' => 'my_controller',
        'action'     => 'my_action'
    )
);

$router->addRoute('my_route', $route);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this router? In the doc says in Controller.  Is it controllers/myController.php?

Comment: Vartec's route is more efficient and better in this case